# Syntax error using Javascript in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

For my project in Rails 4, I am working with part of the code in JavaScript but I am having an error in the console. When working directly with numbers this error disappear. I explain it better with the code:

Here is the javascript's code in `index.html.erb`

```
<script >

$(function(){

// Converting entries by user 
    var jahresverbrauch; 
    jahresverbrauch = parseInt(a); //Jahreshausverbrauch (kWh)
    var pv_groeße; 
    pv_groeße = parseInt(b); //PV-Große (kWp)
    var strompreis; 
    strompreis = parseFloat(c); //Strompreis (cent)
    var strompreissteigerung; 
    strompreissteigerung = parseFloat(d); //Stromsteigerung (cent)
    var ertrag_pv; 
    ertrag_pv = parseInt(e); //Ertrag PV (kWh/kWp)
    var degression_pv; 
    degression_pv = parseFloat(f); //Degression_pv (%)
    var pv_preis_inst; 
    pv_preis_inst = parseInt(g); //PV-Anlagepreis(+Installation pro kWp)
    var einspeiseverguetung; 
    einspeiseverguetung = parseFloat(h); //PV-Anlagepreis(+Installation pro kWp)
    var foerderung; 
    foerderung = i;



      $.ajax({ 
      type: 'POST', 
      url: '/api/v2/energycalcsb', 
      data: {"data":[jahresverbrauch,pv_groeße]}, 
      dataType: 'json', 
      success: function(data){ //Sending the output to a function
        finance_module(data); 

      } 
      }); //AJAX to energy calculation module



    function finance_module(data){


        eigen_eco4 = data['data_output'][0];
        autarkie_eco4 = data['data_output'][1];

        eigen_eco6 = data['data_output'][2];
        autarkie_eco6 = data['data_output'][3];

        eigen_eco8 = data['data_output'][4];
        autarkie_eco8 = data['data_output'][5];

        eigen_eco10 = data['data_output'][6];
        autarkie_eco10 = data['data_output'][7];

        eigen_eco12 = data['data_output'][8];
        autarkie_eco12 = data['data_output'][9];

        eigen_eco14 = data['data_output'][10];
        autarkie_eco14 = data['data_output'][11];

        eigen_eco16 = data['data_output'][12];
        autarkie_eco16 = data['data_output'][13];


       //{"data":[52,55,60,65,67,65,67,69,70,72,72,74,73,76,jahresverbrauch,pv_groeße,strompreis,strompreissteigerung,ertrag_pv,degression_pv,pv_preis_inst,einspeiseverguetung,foerderung]},

         $.ajax({ 
         type: 'POST', 
         url: '/api/v3/financecalc', 
         data: {"data":[eigen_eco4,autarkie_eco4,eigen_eco6,autarkie_eco6,eigen_eco8,autarkie_eco8,eigen_eco10,autarkie_eco10,70,72,eigen_eco14,autarkie_eco14,eigen_eco16,autarkie_eco16,jahresverbrauch,pv_groeße,strompreis,strompreissteigerung,ertrag_pv,degression_pv,pv_preis_inst,einspeiseverguetung,foerderung]}, //HERE-> PROBLEM
         dataType: 'json', 
         success: function(data){ 
           results(data);
           //console.log('success', data); 
         } 
         }); //AJAX to energy calculation module



    };

      function results(data){

        eco_nummer = data['data_output'][0][0][0];
        gewinn = data['data_output'][0][0][1];
        amortisation = data['data_output'][1][0][1];

        //console.log('success', data['data_output'][0][0][0]); //data=[data_output=[[[4,6355],[6,3545]],[[4,5],[6,8]]]]
        if ( jahresverbrauch != 0 && pv_groeße != 0 && isNaN(strompreis) == false  && isNaN(strompreissteigerung) == false && ertrag_pv != 0 && isNaN(degression_pv) == false && pv_preis_inst != 0 && isNaN(einspeiseverguetung) == false && foerderung != "")//"0", "0", "NaN", "NaN", "0", "NaN", "0", "NaN", ""
        {
          $("#o1").text("out1 "+eco_nummer);
          $("#o2").text("out2 "+gewinn + "€");
          $("#o3").text("out3 "+amortisation);
        }



      };

});

</script>
```

This is my controller (how I receive the data from AJAX):

```
class Api::V3::FinancecalcController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
    def index

    end

    def create

          eigen_eco4 = params[:data][0].to_f
          autarkie_eco4 = params[:data][1].to_f

          eigen_eco6 = params[:data][2].to_f
          autarkie_eco6 = params[:data][3].to_f

          eigen_eco8 = params[:data][4].to_f
          autarkie_eco8 = params[:data][5].to_f

        eigen_eco10 = params[:data][6].to_f
          autarkie_eco10 = params[:data][7].to_f

          eigen_eco12 = params[:data][8].to_f
          autarkie_eco12 = params[:data][9].to_f

          eigen_eco14 = params[:data][10].to_f
          autarkie_eco14 = params[:data][11].to_f

          eigen_eco16 = params[:data][12].to_f
          autarkie_eco16 = params[:data][13].to_f

          jahrstromverbrauch = params[:data][14].to_f
          pv_groeße = params[:data][15].to_f    
          akt_strompreis_cent = params[:data][16].to_f
          strompreissteigerung = params[:data][17].to_f
          ertrag_pv = params[:data][18].to_f
          degression_pv = params[:data][19].to_f
          pv_preis_inst = params[:data][20].to_f
          einspeiseverguetung = params[:data][21].to_f
          foerderung = params[:data][22].to_s

          # some operations done

          # Save in hash
          autarkie_eco = {4 => autarkie_eco4, 6 => autarkie_eco6, 8 =>   autarkie_eco8, 10 => autarkie_eco10, 12 => autarkie_eco12, 14 => autarkie_eco14, 16 => autarkie_eco16}
    eigenverbrauch_eco = {4 => eigen_eco4, 6 => eigen_eco6, 8 => eigen_eco8, 10 => eigen_eco10, 12 => eigen_eco12, 14 => eigen_eco14, 16 => eigen_eco16}

        # some operations done

        # output back to AJAX


    end     

end
```

The error happens when calling the AJAX when the data refers to: `eigen_eco4,autarkie_eco4` ans so on, and the console log points to: `financecalc`.

When changing these data directly with numbers (23,34 for each `eigen_eco4,autarkie_eco4` etc) it does not appear.

Does anyone have any idea of what I am missing?

Comment: Didn't we have a conversation last week about storing all your data in a hash rather than a hundred different variables?

Comment: Sure, I did as you suggested in (# some operations done). So should I save the params[:data] in a hash?

Comment: Generally, it will make your life easier if you pass your data around in a hash rather than lots of variables.  Your strategy should be that the javascript knows as little about your model logic as possible, instead just pulling data off the page (or user actions) and sending it back to the server.

Comment: Thx for the advise. The problem in this case was that the AJAX (/api/v2/energycalcsb) was starting the call before the form was filled out. With an if condition was fixed.